# combining several if statement for one input in java

Tags: java, if-statement, nested-if

im begginer in java , could anyone tell me how to combine several if in one input.

I mean something like this "

> how old are you?"

when user answer this it works with several if forexample my code is :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int age = 40;
    Scanner ageField = new Scanner (System.in);
         System.out.print("How old are you? ");
     if(ageField.nextDouble() > age ){
         System.out.print("you are over than 40 years old"); 

     }else if(ageField.nextDouble() < age ){
         System.out.print("you are less than 40");


     }else if(ageField.nextDouble() < 20 ){
         System.out.print("you are less than 20");
         }else {

             System.out.print("enter your age");
         }
    }
}
```

i mean the answer should based on the given value,hope you get what im saying

Comment: Get the value of `ageFields.nextDouble()` _once_, store in a variable. The `.nextDouble()` is a blocking call that actually reads the input.

Comment: Are you referencing the `age <40` block? For example, do you want to check if their age is less than 20 inside the less than 40 block?

Comment: i mean , the question should have diffrent answer , forexample if the age given more than 40 it should print that "you are over than 40" and if the given value is less than 30 it should print "you are less than 30" and if less than 20 it should print "you are less than 20" , you know what im saying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will not work because you are calling `nextDouble()` several times. Instead, store the age variable in an `int` and perform your if statements against this age variable.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("How old are you? ");
int age = sc.nextInt();

if(age > 40){
  System.out.print("You are more than 40");
}else if(age < 40 && age >= 30){
  System.out.print("You are less than 40");
} else if(age < 30) {
  System.out.print("You are less than 30");
}
....
```

Comment: its worked , really thanks sir , now this topic became clear for me , going to continue learning other toturials of java,can i have your telegram username?

Comment: i've already upvoted you,would you please give me your telegram username , im really intersted to learn java as well,and i need someone to get help

Comment: or maybe u dont like to share it with me :/ ok bro anyway thanks<3

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because you are discarding the user input ate checking the 1st conditional **if**...

Store the user input (which BTW should be an integer instead of a double)

```
ageField.nextInt()
```

In a variable and use that in the if else conditions... no need to call get Double several times

Answer (score 1):

Here's actually one of possible optimization OP has asked for. One `if` statement that can be reused as much as needed. The program will ask for input for the number of your items in `ages` list:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        List<Integer> ages = Arrays.asList("20", "40").stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
        try (Scanner ageField = new Scanner(System.in))
        {
            System.out.print("How old are you? ");
            ages.forEach(e -> analyzeAge(ageField.nextInt(), e));
        }
    }

    private static void analyzeAge(int ageInput, int ageCompared)
    {
        String answer = null;
        if (ageInput > ageCompared)
        {
            answer = "You are older than " + ageCompared;
        }
        else if (ageInput < ageCompared)
        {
            answer = "You are younger than " + ageCompared;
        }
        else
        {
            answer = "You are exactly " + ageCompared + " years old";
        }
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Was responding the same thing but on mobile it's too damn hard to do fast. Would replace "equally" with "exactly" though.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've updated the code accordingly. I'm on PC, so was faster =)

Comment: thanks Ivan Pronin , because im new to java i just wanted to use only Scanner and if statement  , i wanted to ask if its possible to do what i meant using Scanner and nested if or not,anyway thanks for answering guys <3